# How to Create a DAPP without metamask

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, voting-system

I want to make a voting system with ethereum.
I referred to this. : https://romeoh.tistory.com/entry/Solidity-Front-end-%EA%B5%AC%EB%8F%99%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0?category=340661
It was possible to vote by implementing the Web.
But I had to press the approval button directly using metamask. Is it possible to proceed voting and pay gas without metamask extension program in Chrome?

If so, please let me know what method or algorithm you need.
Also, if you have a link to refer to, I'd appreciate it if you could attach a link.

Comment: You only use metamask for your ease. If you dont want to use metamask you can implement your own wallet logic, but ofcourse it will need alot of time and expertise..

Comment: Hi! You can do it without metamask. You could use the Web3j library to implement your aplication.

Comment: how can do that? please let me know how to make it! Could you upload some links about that?

Comment: @Urko I have the same problem. Can I use web3.js and a geth / parity node? is it the "same thing" as using metamask?

Comment: Yes, of course. Metamask is a wallet to interact with some Blockchain networks. With the web3.js library, you could develop your applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use metamask to sign the transaction. To sign your transaction without metamask u would need private key and public key of the account with which you want to make transaction. after that you can follow this [etherum stack exchange link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/how-to-make-transactions-using-private-key-in-web3) which shows how to make transaction with private key

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this with out metamask, As you will be needing a wallet to connect with web3 and perform task on blockchain/ Calling functions in your smart contract. It's like you want to ride a bicycle without peddles.

If you are looking for options other than metamask then you can try to use Mist browser.

Comment: You can do everything without metamask. Its just an extension to make your work easy and that way you dont have to spend alot of time implementing your own wallet.

Comment: Exactly that what I want to say is you need a wallet. Its on you whether you use metamask or mist browser. Or if you can create your own wallet.